# "failed to detect ESP32 chip" but actually found and worked

Tags: hardware, provisioning, toit

While trying to provision an ESP32 I am getting a warning "failed to detect ESP32 chip". Of course, I selected "No" to the question "Do you want to continue? [y/n]".... how can I proceed if no ESP32 was detected... However, just for fun I answered Yes, and to my surprise, all the provision went well.

What is going on here?

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESP32 detection in this case is done by calling `esptool.py read_mac` (with some additional flags).
It seems like that command doesn't always succeed, even if it can then flash the device.

I filed https://github.com/toitware/public/issues/11. At the very least inviting users to still try to flash the device is probably an improvement.